# What is the action of the use of a Fortran array constructor func((/array(i)/))

Tags: arrays, fortran

I am reviewing a fortran (95/2003) code which contains a statement of the form

```
  do j=1,size(array)
    res(j) = func((/array(j)/))
  end do
```

where func is a `function` which takes a single array 1-dimensional of size `size(array)` as argument. I understand that the `(/ ... /)` is an array constructor. But what is the purpose of the `func((/array(j)/))` statement? Note that the sample is reduced of curse and I hope that I didn't remove relevant parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, `func` is some function that accepts an array as input and returns a scalar.

`array(j)` is just a scalar, so you cannot pass that to `func` directly. So you construct an array of dimension 1 by `(/ array(j) /)` and pass that temporary array to your function.

As agentp pointed out [thanks!], the following would also pass a dimension-1 array (to be precise, an array slice of length 1):

```
func( array(j:j) )
```

Comment: So the function `func` takes a variable-length array as argument and is supposedly written such that it evaluates also if the array has length 1?

Comment: I would guess so, but I can't be sure without seeing the code of `func`... But you mentioned that it accepts an array of length one!

Comment: The routine is to long to see this immediately, but from the context it is now clear to me that it should be such.

Comment: would this do the same: `func(array(j:j))` ?